# Dynamic SQL : next value for sequence fails

Tags: sql, dynamic, sequence, sql-server-2014

I am struggling to get values from the sequence when executing dynamic SQL which executes a stored procedure. Can I even do this?

I'm using SQL Server 2014. Here's my error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 116
>   Incorrect syntax near 'NEXT'.

My code:

```
Declare @Script1 NVARCHAR(max);
Declare @ScriptSP1 NVARCHAR(max);
Declare @ScriptSeq1 NVARCHAR(max);
Declare @ScriptExecSP1 NVARCHAR(max);

Set @Script1 = N'Create table dbo.tblParentSponsor(
[ParentSponsorId] INT PRIMARY KEY,
[Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[Surname] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
[Cellphone_Number] CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
[Telephone_Number] CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
[Address] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[Region] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[Email] NVARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
[ID_Number] CHAR(13) NOT NULL
);'

EXEC sp_executesql @Script1;

Set @ScriptSP1 = N'CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[sp_Insert_Into_tblParentSponsor]
@Id INT,
@Name NVARCHAR(50),
@Surname NVARCHAR(50), 
@Cellphone_Number CHAR(10),
@Telephone_Number CHAR(10),
@Address NVARCHAR(50),
@Region NVARCHAR(50),
@Email NVARCHAR(254),
@ID_Number CHAR(13)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.tblParentSponsor(ParentSponsorId,Name,Surname,Cellphone_Number,Telephone_Number,Address,Region,Email,ID_Number)
VALUES(@Id,@Name,@Surname,@Cellphone_Number,@Telephone_Number,@Address,@Region,@Email,@ID_Number)
END'

EXEC sp_executesql @ScriptSP1;

SET @ScriptSeq1 = 'CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.TestS 
 AS [int]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1'

EXEC sp_executesql @ScriptSeq1;

SET @ScriptExecSP1 = 'dbo.[sp_Insert_Into_tblParentSponsor] NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.TestS,S,S,1,1,1,1,1,1;'

EXEC sp_executesql @ScriptExecSP1;
```

Comment: You have multiple issues.  Your first parameter is @Id which is an int.  However, the first value you are passing in is not int.  None of your string parameters are enclosed in quotes.  Basically, the error message is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would work for you?

```
DECLARE @nextValue INT;

SET @nextValue = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.TestS

SET @ScriptExecSP1 = 'dbo.[sp_Insert_Into_tblParentSponsor] ' +
                     CAST( @nextValue AS VARCHAR(10) ) + 
                     ',''S'',''S'',''1'',''1'',''1'',''1'',''1'',''1'';'

EXEC sp_executesql @ScriptExecSP1;
```

(Use whatever casting or converting method you want to get @nextValue to a string.)

Comment: Thanks for trying, I did test it but it doesn't work. I don't think we can execute a stored procedure with parameters using dynamic SQL